# Does anybody know where could I find the documentaton about the clustergrid in seaborn clustermap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The clustermap returns a clustergrid, I want to know all the option I could add behind the clustergrid 'g' as the code showed below. I could not found the detailed documentation in seaborn. Does anybody could help？

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.clustermap(iris, col_cluster=False, yticklabels=False)
g.cax.set_position([.15, .2, .03, .45])
g.ax_heatmap.XXX
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are tools to get information of objects in Python.  Part of the problem is that your code gets hung up at the creation of `g`, (which of course is maybe why you want documentation!).  But using the example from the [`seaborn` docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
```

You can do `dir(g)` to get all its attributes:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 ...
 'row_colors',
 'savefig',
 'set',
 'standard_scale',
 'z_score']
```

You can also call `help(g)` to get the docstring for `ClusterGrid`:

```
class ClusterGrid(seaborn.axisgrid.Grid)
 |  ClusterGrid(data, pivot_kws=None, z_score=None, standard_scale=None, figsize=None, row_colors=None, col_colors=None, mask=None)
 |  
 |  Base class for grids of subplots.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      ClusterGrid
 |      seaborn.axisgrid.Grid
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
...
...
...
```

You can use `type(g)` to get the full object type:

```
seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid
```

Which can show you the path through the `seaborn` source to get its definition [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/79051edcd81af4ce3c3abd06f01eb28478a9a53a/seaborn/matrix.py#L789).

You could also use the built-in [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to get more information for `seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid`.

```
>>>print(inspect.getsource(seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid)) #for getting source code
class ClusterGrid(Grid):
    def __init__(self, data, pivot_kws=None, z_score=None, standard_scale=None,
                 figsize=None, row_colors=None, col_colors=None, mask=None):
        """Grid object for organizing clustered heatmap input on to axes"""
...
...
...

>>>print(inspect.getfullargspec(seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid)) #for getting arguments
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'data', 'pivot_kws', 'z_score', 'standard_scale', 'figsize', 'row_colors', 'col_colors', 'mask'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None, None, None, None, None, None, None), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

*I also cannot find online documentation for the record.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I decided to go to the code of `Seaborn` in github.
Once there, a quick tricky is to use the `github1s.com` for searching the repo using VSCode.

You can find the code here: [seaborn/matrix.py#L795](https://github1s.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/matrix.py#L795). I guess that this can help orient better.

Even though seaborn does not have full documentation yet, the Clustermap is really pretty and useful.